# Using javascript function to load a view

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller

I trying to load a view into my div #teste with this.id through JavaScript without success. What's wrong on my function?

JavaScript function below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var baseurl = '<?php site_url(); ?>'; //raiz do website

function navbutton(id) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: baseurl+'main/'+id,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html) {
            $('#teste').html(html);
        }
    });
    }
```

HTML button

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="contato" onclick="navbutton(this.id)">Contato</a></li>
```

My main Controller (one function to call all others views)

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

var $_data = array();

public function index()
{
    if (!$this->uri->segment(1) && !$this->uri->segment(2)) {
        $view = 'inicio';
    }
    if ($this->uri->segment(1) && !$this->uri->segment(2)) {
        $view = $this->uri->segment(1, 'inicio');
    }
    if ($this->uri->segment(1) && $this->uri->segment(2)) {
        $view = $this->uri->segment(1, 'inicio') . '/' . $this->uri->segment(2, '');
    }
    if (!file_exists(APPPATH . 'views/' . $view . EXT)) {
        $view = "404";
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    }

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view($view, $this->_data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

Comment: could you explain where you have errors? or what actually happen? Please get more details to give you needed answer

Comment: are the ajax base url same with browser ? because javascript has "Same origin policy"

Comment: i sugest to add    error:function(v1,v2,v3){ alert('Something went wrong'); } on ajax , after sucess: { ....} to catch some response errors

Comment: i always get 'Uncaught ReferenceError: navbutton is not defined' even with $(document).ready(function()

Comment: take a look on my last edit of answer. If you have already solved, please add here your solution.

Answer (score 1):

to avoid to get 'Uncaught ReferenceError: navbutton is not defined'  error
attach on click event function with javascript:

```
var baseurl = '<?php site_url(); ?>'; //raiz do website
function navbutton(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: baseurl+'main/'+id,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html) {
            $('#teste').html(html);
        },
        error:function(v1,v2,v3){
            alert('Something went wrong'); }
    });
}

$("#contato").on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    navbutton(this.id);
});
```

And on **HTML** use

```
<li><a href="#" id="contato">Contato</a></li>
```

[JSFIDLE test](http://jsfiddle.net/5zqwesog/6/) - in this example the ajax request will get error 404 because the url is not defined proper but in you code must work.

**HINT** to make sure all code is in the proper place, take a look in the source code of page after is loaded in browser (CTRL+U)

Comment: on my console still report an error.`Uncaught ReferenceError: navbutton is not defined`

Comment: add the declaration of navbutton before to use-it in html onclick

Comment: the example works fine, even with codeigniter -function is declared before my button-, but correction doesn't work with full code. i think is something wrong with ajax instructions, but idk what.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load string to element? In that case you need to pass third argument TRUE when loading view method.

```
$view = $this->load->view('templates/header', '', TRUE);
$view .= $this->load->view($view, $this->_data, TRUE);
$view .= $this->load->view('templates/footer', '', TRUE);
echo $view;
```

Check in [docs here](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data).

Comment: I trying to render/load partial view. Load a page with javascript without refresh on codeigniter.

Comment: I've just pointed at how you can make a string not making page load. If you use ajax to get that string, although you need to post identifier for specific page, it could work.